# Random graph uniformly sample from the special graphs

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

We know two basic random graph models:$G(n,p)$ and $G(n,m)$. $G(n,m)$ consists of all graphs with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, in which the graphs have the same probability. We know that $G(n,p)$ and $G(n,m)$ are asymptotically equivalent when $C_n^2 p=m$. So when we want to calculate the probability of some property in $G(n,m)$, we can calculate it in $G(n,p)$, which is much easier.

Now, if we wang to study the random graph that consists of all graphs that have some property(such as all graphs that are $d$-regular graph with $\chi'=d$), in which the graphs have the same probability, we don't have similar asymptotic equivalence, how do we calculate the probability of some property? Are there any papers that study similar random graph models?

Comment: Certainly there are many papers about uniform regular graphs, look for  Bollobas' "Random graphs".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a notion of *contiguity* for models of graphs. Two sequences of probability spaces
$$\{(\Omega_n, \mathcal{F}_n, P_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \text{ and } \{(\Omega_n, \mathcal{F}_n, \tilde{P}_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$$
(with the same underlying measurable spaces $(\Omega_n, \mathcal{F}_n)$) are *contiguous* if any event that occurs in the first sequence with probability $1$ as $n\to \infty$ also occurs in the second sequence with probability $1$ as $n \to \infty$.

There are several papers about models for random $d$-regular graphs that are contiguous with the uniform model. One of these models is the following: take $d$ random matchings on the vertex set $[n]$ (assuming $n$ is even). Assuming they have no joint edges, take their union. If they do have some common edges, try to generate random matchings again. Graphs in this model all have $\chi' = d$ (give each matching a different color).

See Wormald's survey on models of random regular graphs, and also:

S. Janson, Random regular graphs: Asymptotic distributions and contiguity, Combinatorics, Probability and Computing, 4 (1995), 369–405.

M. Molloy, H. Robalewska, R. W. Robinson & N. C. Wormald, 1-
factorisations of random regular graphs, Random Structures & Algorithms, 10 (1997), 305–321.

Comment: Thank you! I think contiguity is equals asymptotically equivalent, that is, $P(G_1\in Q )=1$ as $n$ tends to inifinity $\rightarrow $ $P(G_2\in Q)=1$ as $n$ tends to inifinity for some property $Q$.

Comment: @zhukuibai I'm not so familiar with the terminology, but if that's the case the statement about $G(n,p)$ in your question seems inaccurate: the probability that $G(n,p)$ will have exactly $m={n \choose 2}p$ edges goes to $0$ as $n\to \infty$, so a sequence of the form $\{G(n_i, p_i)\}_i$ can't be contiguous with one of the form $\{G(n_i, m_i)\}_i$ if $n_i \to \infty$ as $i \to \infty$.

Comment: In fact, $m \approx C_n^2p$ is enough. Here, always $p=p(n), m=m(n)$. We have $C_n^2p \approx m$ and So $C_n^2p  \neq 0$. Then I think that the form ${G(n_i,p_i)}$ can be contiguous with one of the form ${G(n_i,m_i)}$.

Comment: @zhukuibai I think this can't work: take $p=\frac{1}{2}$, define $m_i$ as you suggest, and for each $i$ let $E_i$ be the event that $G$ has precisely $m_i$ edges. Then in the sequence $\{G(n_i,p_i)\}_i$ we have $\lim_i P(E_i) = 0$, because the number of edges has a binomial distribution and $P(E_i) < \frac{1}{\sqrt{m_i}}$ for large enough $i$. But in the sequence $\{G(n_i, m_i)\}_i$ we have $\lim_i P(E_i) = 1$.

Comment: Why $P(E_i)<\frac{1}{\sqrt{m_i}}$?

Comment: @zhukuibai This follows from Stirling's estimate. The number of edges in $G(n,p)$ is distributed binomially. There are a total of $N={n \choose 2}$ possible edges, of which we choose some subset. If $p=\frac{1}{2}$ and $m= N/2 = pN$, the probability of getting exactly $m$ edges is ${2m \choose m} p^m (1-p)^m$ (note $N=2m$), which equals $4^{-m} {2m \choose m}$, which Stirling shows is approximately $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi m}}$. If you take $m\neq N/2$, the probability is only smaller, because the middle binomial coefficient is the maximal one.

Comment: I find some mistakes. The probability of getting exactly $m$ edges is not $\left(\begin{array}{c}2 m \\ m\end{array}\right) p^m(1-p)^m$. In fact, the probability of getting no exactly $m$ edges is at most $\left(\begin{array}{c}2 m \\ m\end{array}\right) (1-p^m(1-p)^m)$.  By https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model. The expected number of edges in G(n, p) is  $\tbinom{n}{2}p$, and by the law of large numbers any graph in G(n, p) will almost surely have approximately this many edges.

Comment: What I wrote seems fine. We defined $m={n \choose 2}/2$ and $p=1/2$. There are precisely ${{n \choose 2} \choose m} = {2m \choose m}$ graphs on $n$ labelled vertices with precisely $m$ edges. We get a given one of them with probability $p^m (1-p)^{{n \choose 2} - m} = p^m (1-p)^m$. Therefore the probability of getting one of these graphs is precisely ${2m \choose m} p^m (1-p)^m = {2m \choose m} 4^{-m}$. When you quote that "any graph in $G(n,p)$ will almost surely have approximately this many edges" it only means that the number of edges is concentrated in an interval of length $o(m)$.

Comment: @zhukuibai Your estimate ${2m \choose m}(1-p^m(1-p)^m)$ is larger than $1$ for large $m$ and $p=1/2$. It doesn't mean much to interpret it as an upper bound on a probability.

Comment: If we denote event that get a given one of them by $A_i$. Then $P(A_i)=p^m(1-p)^m$. The probability of getting one of these graphs is $P(\cup A_i)$. I think that if all $A_i$ are independent, your canculate is right.

Comment: Maybe your probability is  a good upper bound.  The property of containing exactly $m$ edges serves as a counterexample, we need that property is monotone.